# Why do I keep getting php error saying unexpected ')' in FOR statement?

Tags: php, html

I am programming an HTML 10x10 table, Each cell with a separate ID and link. It was taking way to long with copying and pasting and changing so I decided to use PHP, using the FOR command which I am not very familiar with.

I am using this code:

```
<table>
<?php 
for ($r=1, $r<10,$r++) {
;echo "<TR>";
for ($d=1, $d<10,$d++) {
echo "<TR id='d" . $d . "r" . $r . "'><a href='javascript: void(0)' onclick='shoot(" . $d . "," . $r . ")'>SHOOT!</a>";
}
echo "<TD>";
} 
?>
</table>
```

PHP is saying:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\****\*****\index.php on line 16
```

i starred out the stuf I do not want you to see.

I am using Windows 7 with [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) version 1.7.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a **semicolon** (`;`) in your `for` loop (instead of a comma).

And please indent your code, it makes it a lot easier to read...

Something like this:

```
for ($r=1; $r<10; $r++) {
    echo "<TR>";
    for ($d=1; $d<10; $d++) {
        echo "<TR id='d".$d."r".$r."'><a href='javascript: void(0)' onclick='"
             ."shoot(".$d.",".$r.")'>SHOOT!</a>";
    }
    echo "<TD>";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `;` instead of `,` to delimit the statements in the for loop expression. You can read more about php's for loop syntax [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Answer (score 4):

The `for` syntax is:

```
for(intro; comp; inc) expr;
```

Notice the `;` instead of `,` inside the `for`.

Answer (score 2):

The statements inside the for-loop should be separated by semicolons, not commas.  For example: for ($r=1; $r<10;$r++) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

Don't for loops have the conditions separated by semicolons?

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($r=1, $r<10,$r++)
```

should be

```
for ($r=1; $r<10; $r++)
```

Your for statements are using commas instead of semi-colons.

The PHP [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) can be a big help.