# Why am I getting an unexpected eof?

Tags: php, html

I am working on coding this up with a mixture of PHP and HTML but I can't seem to understand why I am getting an eof yet when I exclude the middle php part, it works just fine. i can't seem to understand why it is giving me an error. I compared it to another part of my program and when I looked at a similar page, it works but this one is simply giving me an unexpected eof

Here is the code. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
   require_once( "data.php" );
   error_reporting(0);
?>

<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Course Listings</h1>
      </div>
      <table class="table">
      <?php
        foreach( $data as $value  )
        {
      ?>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="course.php"> <? $value[number] ?> </a></td>
        <td> <? $value[name] ?> </td>
        <td> <? $value[instructor] ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?
           };
      ?>
      </table>
  </div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most likely because of the semi-colon in `};` - Remove it.

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled? Otherwise you need to use <?php code ?> everywhere

Comment: also may be `<?` should be `<?=`

Comment: Why are you mixing `<?php` with `<?` ... just be consistent, and remember the shorthand style needs to be enabled.

Comment: Also change `<? $value[name] ?>` to `<?= $value[name] ?>` <=(Short tags) or `<?php echo $value[name] ?>` and do the same for the other one. You may even want to add quotes `$value['name']` depending on what you're trying to fetch from DB, which looks to be the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I keep getting php error saying unexpected ')' in FOR statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285019/why-do-i-keep-getting-php-error-saying-unexpected-in-for-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing bracket of your foreach is not being processed because short tags are disabled. This causes the unexpected eof because php still expects a closing bracket.

Use the standard tag `<?php` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Fred-ii most likely had it right in his comment. if that doesn't completely solve it, replace your `<table>` contents with this and see if it works. As the other guys mentioned, you may have an issue with `<?=`

```
<table class="table">
<?php foreach($data as $value ): ?>
<tr>
<td><a href="course.php"> <?php echo $value['number']; ?> </a></td>
<td> <?php echo $value['name']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $value['instructor']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```